# Firestore Query where field may be nested at multiple levels

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Imagine a document structure like the following where a field like `itemId` may exist at multiple, nested levels:

```
items: [
  {
    title: 'Heading 1',
    items: [
       {itemId: 123, itemTitle: 'Foo' },
       {itemId: 456, itemTitle: 'Bar' },
    ],
  },
  {itemId: 789, itemTitle: 'Baz' },
]
```

Is there an efficient query where I can say something like, *Find any document where `itemId == 456'*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no query that can do what you want, with the document structure you show here.  The problem is that `itemId` exists inside an array field, and **array fields can't be queried for specific key or value data**.  There are no workarounds for this structure.

What you will have to do is introduce a new field into this document that includes all of the included `itemId` values in a single field that can be queried.  It could be an array field where the items of the array are itemId strings.  If you do this, you will use an [array-contains type query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership) to find the `itemId` you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, this is what I thought.  I figured that I would ask just in case there was a better way.  Thanks for your help.